# React project can't find a file anymore after I changed its extension from .js to .tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I created my React project using `npx create-react-app my-app` and installed Typescript, but after changing one of my components to a .tsx file, my project started giving me the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './contexts/AuthContext' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\firebase-authentication\src'
```

The import was working before changing the extension to .tsx

Comment: Follow [Adding TypeScript to an existing Create React App project guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/#installation).

Answer (score 1):

React compiles JS files and TS files differently, So you have to change the file extension in the import to include (.tsx) as well for it to run appropriately.

Also take note that Typescript files should include type definitions for variables, functions etc. So you might have to fix that depending on your code